# How to write sanskrit vowels on their with Ubuntu 14.04 sanskrit keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I'm using the Sanskrit (KaGaPa phonetic) keyboard in Ubuntu 14.04 and am unable to write the vowel "e" on its own in front of a word. I simply get a circle with what "e" looks like with a consonant like so - े

How do I get "e" on its own?

Please advise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

it seems late now, but maybe useful for someone:
right alt + e = ऎ
right alt + shift + e = ए

click on keyboard layout / Keyboard Layout Chart to see the alphabet layout.